# Azure CosmosDB how to query against a physical partition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to execute a very large query that needs to return millions of records, so I want to partition the query and use multiple machines to process the results.

My logical partition key would be a UUID of a document, so that will not be very helpful for me to allocate different parts to each worker node. Can I get the physical partition ID and execute my query only within a particular physical partition?

Here's what I have tried:

```
FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions();
feedOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(false);
feedOptions.setPartitionKeyRangeIdInternal("0");

client.queryDocuments(collectionPath, "SELECT * FROM e where e.docType
= 'address'", feedOptions).flatMapIterable(FeedResponse::getResults);
```

But changing the partitionKeyRangeId doesn't seem to change the results at all.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, it can't be performed within a particular physical partition so far. I could't find any parameters related to physical partition in [Cosmos DB Rest Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents). The [PartitionKeyRangeId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-request-headers) you mentioned in your code is used in [change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) requests.

Based on the statement in [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data), we can't manage physical partitions in cosmos db:

> Azure Cosmos DB will automatically scale the number of physical
>   partitions based on your workload. So you shouldn’t corelate your
>   database design based on the number of physical partitions instead you
>   should make sure to choose the right partition key which determines
>   the logical partitions.

However, since cosmos db is flexible,available and enlightened, you could submit [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to ask for further assistant if you do have such requirements related to physical partitions.

Hope it helps you.

---

***Update Answer:***

There are many ways to improve the performance of processing large volumes of data, I just give some personal advice here.

1.You could tried to consider choosing a partition key that is more appropriate than the `UUID` for greatly improve performance.

2.Try using `page size` to limit the number of items per query, then implement query and  process parallelism by multithreading.

3.Increase the RUs setting to promote performance.

More ideas,please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to achieve parallel batch processing? Let's say the query will return a huge number of documents, and for each document, I have a heavy workload to process on them. How can I parallelize the process and make it faster?

Comment: @zhouchong90 Please see my update answer. You could mark my answer if you think it's useful for you. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answers. However, I don’t think you solved my problem. To utilize cosmosDB effectively, I want to use the primary key to be the partition key so that it will not become an issue to reach 10G data. And I want to achieve parallelism to a cluster of nodes. CosmosDB itself will have a high performance, but the application I’ll develop will take time as it’ll need to call a bunch of 3rd party APIs to process each document.